# Ubuntu 16.04 Can not run npm run / install /rebuild

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

what heppens after npm install rebuild or npm install  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfTjM.png)
,then it's show Error like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7obI.png)

This is the error I get when I run npm run [my project]

```
Error: uncaughtException: The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"
Original error: Cannot find module '/home/itsaraphap/Documents/blockchainSampran2/api-sampran/node_modules/fabric-network/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'
Require stack:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this

```
npm install grpc@1.20.2
```